# Too weak to give in, too strong to lose

Tags: meaning

In Foo fighters' song 'Best of you' singer says

```
I was too weak to give in,
too strong to lose
```

I always thought that 'give in' was the opposite of 'give up'
so for me that sentence suggested an interior struggle: being too weak to put more energy in something but being strong enough to not give up.

It turns out 'give in' means 'surrender' but 'I was too weak to surrender' doesn't seem logical to me; so what does it mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just means as you say "too weak to surrender". The logical meaning, or lack thereof, of that isn't a matter of English Language & Usage and you've already answered the EL&U part of it. (There is no guarantee that Foo Fighters songs always make logical sense, which is not even necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: It's pprobably a use of paradox (and probably qualifying as oxymoron)  rather than a contradiction in terms. >> I didn't have the moral courage to do what I should have done (give in); [I (stupidly) considered myself] too strong to lose.

Comment: @JonHanna i needed to understand the actual meaning of the sentence, not only grammatically, if so i'd use a dictionary (and I did). People here helped me understand and this is what this kind of sites are all about. i'm not off-topic and even if i am i dont' care cause i got the answer :)

Comment: "Give in" and "give up" mean roughly the same thing (though there are subtle differences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being to weak to surrender isn't illogical. If Dave Grohl says so, maybe he hadn't had the strength to admit to himself, that he lost, acknowledging defeat and there for continued his case altough he knew, he could never win.

Another example: Imagine you did something horribly wrong as a kid, but you don't have the strength to tell it your parents, because you might get punished. Same principle.

Sounds perfectly fine to me.